# Find all limit points for the set $A=\lbrace (\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{m}):n,m\geq 1\rbrace$.

Tags: real-analysis

This was a question on an exam I took recently. When taking the exam I thought the only limit point was $(0,0)$ but that evidently was not the answer considering the amount of credit I lost. Thinking about the problem after the fact, I have found other limit points, such as any $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{n})$, but I can't seem to find a concise notation for ALL the limit points. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4):

As you've worked out, if you fix either $n$ or $m$ in $\{(1/n, 1/m):n,m≥1\}$, you get a limit point where the other variable is zero. As you already know the answer, I'll just give you a concise way of writing it:
\begin{align*}
\{(1/n, 0):n≥1\}\cup\{(0, 1/m):m≥1\}\cup\{(0,0)\}
\end{align*}

**EDIT** A bit more detail:
For a point $a$ to be a limit point of the set, given any ball of radius $\epsilon$ around the point, you need to be able to find another point $b$ so that it's not equal to $a$ but it's also inside the ball.

Consider any point of the form $(\frac{1}{p}, \frac{1}{q})$ where $p, q \in \mathbb{N}$. Then the "nearest points" are $(\frac{1}{p}, \frac{1}{q-1}), (\frac{1}{p}, \frac{1}{q+1}), (\frac{1}{p-1}, \frac{1}{q}),$ and $(\frac{1}{p+1}, \frac{1}{q})$. However, you now know that the distance between them is some constant in terms of $p$ and $q$. For example, the distance from $(\frac{1}{p}, \frac{1}{q})$ to $(\frac{1}{p}, \frac{1}{q-1})$ is $\frac{1}{q(q-1)}$. By choosing an $\epsilon$ less than the minimum of these four "closest values" it's clear that $(\frac{1}{p}, \frac{1}{q})$ can't be a limit point.

Now consider points of the form $(0, \frac{1}{q})$. Then given any $\epsilon > 0$, if you set $p = \lceil\frac{1}{\epsilon}\rceil+1$, you'll see that $(\frac{1}{p}, \frac{1}{q})$ is within epsilon of $(0, \frac{1}{q})$, and it's also not equal to $(0, \frac{1}{q})$. The same proof works for $(\frac{1}{p}, 0)$ and $(0, 0)$

Comment: You forgot $(0,0)$.

Comment: lmao yeah you're right, thank you

Comment: I like the notation, but can you explain why that set is all the limit points? In the question I noted that $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{m})$ was a limit point (or at least I think it is), but this point is not included in your notation. Am I incorrect to say that it is a limit point?

Comment: When you say "m", it doesn't make much sense because it can vary. I assumed you meant there's a limit point as you tend m to infinity, so 1/m is zero. I can add a bit more detail to my answer if you like?

Comment: I see, it doesn't work for all $m$. For instance, $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ is not a limit point since there is clearly a deleted neighborhood around that point that doesn't have any points of $A$, and such an argument holds for any other $m$ I can think of. So the limit points are only as $m\rightarrow\infty$, correct? Or for $n$ in the other part of the union.

Comment: yeah that's right. I'm adding a little bit more detail to my answer.